# List folders that have more than two files over the size of x in it - command line

Tags: linux, command-line

Even better is if it can find directories that have more than two files excluding certain types of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file names do not have newline characters in them, then the following finds all directories with two or more files over the size of 100k:

```
find . -type f -size +100k | sed -r 's|/[^/]*$||' | sort | uniq -d
```

As far as "excluding certain types of files," `find` has many many options for that.

If one has the most recent versions of `sed` installed, then the above approach can be extended to handle hostile file names.  Alternatively, if one has `bash` version 4 available, then use:

```
declare -A a
find . -type f -size +100k -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' fname
do
    dir="$(dirname "$fname")"
    ((a["$dir"]++))
    [[ "${a["$dir"]}" -eq 2 ]] && echo "$dir"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good at shell scripts, but something like this would print out the directories that have more than two files with size of X bytes or bigger

```
#!/bin/sh

for DIR in foo bar; do
    if [ `find $DIR -mindepth 1 -size +Xc | wc -l` -gt 2 ]; then
        echo $DIR
    fi
done
```

I'm not sure what you mean by

> find directories that have more than two files excluding certain types of files

but you can exclude files with certain strings with `-not -name 'foo'`

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as @John1024's answer but it is safe for all possible path names and outputs the names shell quoted.

```
find . -type f -size +100k -print0 | xargs -0 dirname -z | sort -z | uniq -d -z | xargs -0 ls -d --quoting-style=shell
```

The only improvement I know would help is if there was a command that took zero terminated lines shell quoted them and printed them with newlines that could be used rather than abusing `ls`.